# transforming a dataset from rows to columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I want to transform rows of a dataset to column.

```
selection  weight
sel1       0.4
sel2       0.5



selection_1   weight_1    selection_2   weight_2
sel1          0.4         sel2          0.6
```

I tried reshape, but not sure what parameters to use.

Is it possible to make this transformation using base R functions?

Comment: Have you looked into `tidyr::spread()`? It should be able to achieve what you want with ease.

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge I think you'd need to create a `timevar` and `idvar` first to use `reshape`. (Even if `idvar` is a constant here.)

```
df1_wide <- reshape(data = transform(df1,
                                     timevar = seq_len(nrow(df1)),
                                     idvar = 1L),
                    timevar = "timevar",
                    idvar = "idvar",
                    direction = "wide",
                    sep = "_")
df1_wide
#  idvar selection_1 weight_1 selection_2 weight_2
#1     1        sel1      0.4        sel2      0.5
```

You can unselect `idvar` by

```
cols_to_keep <- setdiff(names(df1_wide), "idvar")
df1_wide[cols_to_keep]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kludgy, but works.

For the example, I'll build the dataframe you described:

```
selection <- c('sel1','sel2')
weight <- c(0.4,0.5)
df <- data.frame(selection = selection,weight = weight)
```

To start, make sure that the `selection` variable is `character` type, not a `factor`.

```
df$selection <- as.character(df$selection)
```

To create the list of names for the new dataframe, we create the correct strings and paste in the indices.

```
indices <- sort(c(1:nrow(df),1:nrow(df)))
tags <- c(rbind(rep(names(df)[1],nrow(df)),rep(names(df)[2],nrow(df))))
new_names <- sapply(1:(2*nrow(df)),function(j) paste(tags[j],indices[j],sep="_"))
```

And here's the kludgy part, written as a function.  Let's step through one by one and add new variables to an empty data frame.

```
make_new_df <- function(df) { 
  new_df <- data.frame()
  for (i in (1:length(new_names))) {
    test <- i %% ncol(df)
    if (test == 0) {
      row_index <- floor(i/ncol(df))
      col_index <- ncol(df)
    } else {
      row_index <- floor(i/ncol(df))+1
      col_index <- (i %% ncol(df))
    }
    new_df[1,new_names[i]] <- df[row_index,col_index]
  }
  return(new_df)
}
```

Let's check that this works for your example:

```
> make_new_df(df)
  selection_1 weight_1 selection_2 weight_2
1        sel1      0.4        sel2      0.5
```

The function `make_new_df` will work for an input dataframe `df` with any number of rows and columns, but it requires the correct configuration for `new_names`.  The preliminary code building `new_names` will work for any number of rows but only two columns (thus it is outside the function).  For example, the code

```
selection <- c('sel1','sel2','sel3','sel4')
weight <- c(0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7)
df <- data.frame(selection = selection,weight = weight)
indices <- sort(c(1:nrow(df),1:nrow(df)))
tags <- c(rbind(rep(names(df)[1],nrow(df)),rep(names(df)[2],nrow(df))))
new_names <- sapply(1:(2*nrow(df)),function(j) paste(tags[j],indices[j],sep="_"))
make_new_df(df)
```

produces

```
  selection_1 weight_1 selection_2 weight_2 selection_3 weight_3 selection_4 weight_4
1        sel1      0.4        sel2      0.5        sel3      0.6        sel4      0.7
```